# problem with the way items are beign rendered in a Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

i am trying to render some dropdown items in a navbar, it appears only the last item of the navbar is being rendered, the logged data appears to be correct, i even hard coded the data into one of the components, the same error still persists.[image: the rendered Navbar] , [image: the logged data].

```
    //Navbar component
    import React from "react";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
    import "./style/navbar.css";

    const Navbar: React.FC = () => {
    const npflDropdownItems = [
    "Home",
    "Fixtures",
    "Results",
    "Tables",
    "Transfer",
    "Stats",
    "Video",
    "Watch Live",
    "Clubs",
    "Players",
    "Awards",
      ];
      const aboutDropdownItems = ["Overview", "What We Do", "Careers", "Partners"];
      const moreDropdownItems = ["Managers", "Referee", "e-NPFL", "Contact Us"];

  console.log(npflDropdownItems, aboutDropdownItems, moreDropdownItems);

  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="logo-container">
        <img className="logo" src="path-to-your-logo.png" alt="Logo" />
      </div>
      <div className="navbar-dropdown">
        <div className="navbar-item npfl">
          Npfl
          <Dropdown items={npflDropdownItems} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="navbar-dropdown">
        <div className="navbar-item about">
          About
          <Dropdown items={aboutDropdownItems} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="navbar-dropdown">
        <div className="navbar-item more">
          More
          <Dropdown items={moreDropdownItems} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

```
//Dropdown component
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

interface DropdownProps {
  items: string[];
}

const Dropdown: React.FC<DropdownProps> = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <div className="navbar-dropdown">
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="navbar-item-dropdown">
          {item}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
`
```

```
`/* Navbar.css */

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo-container {
  max-width: 100px;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.navbar-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-item {

  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-item-dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar-dropdown:hover .navbar-item-dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.fantasy,
.more {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-menu {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .navbar-item,
  .fantasy,
  .more {
    margin: 5px 0;
  }

  .navbar-dropdown .navbar-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
`
```

i expect all the dropdown items to be displayed when clicked or hovered.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with the code. The reason you are not seeing all the nav items is due to `position:absolute`, all the list items are getting overlapped  so you are only seeing the last item.

Also i am seeing that you have a structure like:

```
<div class="navbar-dropdown">
    <div class="navbar-item">
        <div class="navbar-dropdown">
            <div class="navbar-item-dropdown"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am changing the class name slightly to make the outer **navbar-dropdown**, **navbar-dropdown-container**, and changing some styles accordingly.

```
//Navbar component

  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="logo-container">
        <img className="logo" src="path-to-your-logo.png" alt="Logo" />
      </div>
      <div className="navbar-dropdown-container">
        <div className="navbar-item npfl">
          Npfl
          <Dropdown items={npflDropdownItems} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="navbar-dropdown-container">
        <div className="navbar-item about">
          About
          <Dropdown items={aboutDropdownItems} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="navbar-dropdown-container">
        <div className="navbar-item more">
          More
          <Dropdown items={moreDropdownItems} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
```

```
//Navbar.css

//adding some styles to container
.navbar-dropdown-container {
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  z-index: 2;
}

//making navbar-dropdown as display none instead of list items and making its position as absolute
.navbar-dropdown{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
}

//changing some styles for items
.navbar-item-dropdown {
  /* display: none; */
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 100%; */
  /* left: 0; */
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}

//changing hover to target container and adding some styles
.navbar-dropdown-container:hover .navbar-dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

Comment: i applied this changes, and it worked. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in the Dropdown component file, map each of the item in the `items` list to a `<li>` element and wrap it all in the `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Also, you have `display: none` in your `.navbar-item-dropdown` in the stylesheet.

Lastly, if any error is logged in the console, kindly include it in the post, as well.

Comment: thanks for this, someone already provided a working change.